# Accessing iOS native properties/methods from UIwebview from a hybrid app

Tags: ios, c, ipad, mobile, hybrid

I am not an iOS expert. I have a basic question, Is it possible to access/call any Objective C methods/properties  from UI webview? In other words what would happen if i keep some objective C code in a HTML page and load it in UIwebview of an iOS hybrid app? Will the code execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the code will not execute. What you're describing is an "injection" and, if it were possible, could wreak havoc in an app.

Something I've done in the past is create an app with a UIWebView container (somewhat like you're describing) then pass back a response that my code can programmatically look for and handle. This is of course possible by the fact I wrote both the app and the web back-end.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this but it has worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. So if i understand it correctly, if i can control the entire app, i can create some kind of predefined (allowable) interface between the UIwebview and the app to establish this kind of communication?

Comment: Kind of, sort of. If you control both the web page content the app is hitting as well as the app itself you could make an `NSURLConnection` call to your site and have your site return a parameter you're waiting for... something like `callMethod='doSomething'` and react when your app reads that response in `connection:didReceiveData` delegate method. This does of course assume you're adding the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.